# Given a string, get list of tuples (char, how many times the character goes in a row) - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, fold

For example: ʺaaaabbaabʺ->[(‘a’,4),(‘b’,2),(‘a’,2),(‘b’,1)]
Its need to be done using FOLDR through one pass of the list, without using (++).

Here what I have so far

```
task2 (x:xs) = foldr (\c [(symbol, count)] -> if symbol == c then [(symbol, count+1)] else [(symbol, count)]) [(x, 1)] xs
```

The problem is I don't really understand how to make it go to the next element of the list after 'if' statement is False

Comment: try formulating your thoughts about each step first, then approach the problem with code. Right now, your algorithm makes no sense.

Comment: `[(symbol, count)]` is a list of length _one_. Your lambda will crash in any other case (empty list, longer list). You probably don't want to use that as a pattern.

Comment: It seems a bit of a stretch to write the *step function* for `foldr` as an inline lambda expression. I am afraid that can be made to work but makes for an overly long code line. Maybe try something like `taks2 cs = foldr stepFn [] cs  where  stepFn c [] = [(c,1)]` and next the pattern for a non-empty list of pairs.

Comment: "how to make it go to the next element" is exactly what `foldr` does. The point of the exercise is to stop thinking in terms of iteration and start thinking in terms of higher-order operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the step function as an inline lambda expression is probably not the best possible move. It can be made to work, but that leads to a very long line of code.

It is easier to write the step function separately, like this:

```
task2 :: String -> [(Char,Int)]
task2 cs = foldr stepFn [] cs
  where
    stepFn c      []          =  [(c,1)]  -- simple case
    stepFn c ((c1,n1) : ps)   =           -- please try to write the rest ...
```

> if (c == c1)  then  (c1,1+n1) : ps
>                                                else  (c,1) : (c1,n1) : ps

### Testing:

```
$ ghci
 GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> :load q69871708.hs
 [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( q69871708.hs, interpreted )
 Ok, one module loaded.
 λ> 
 λ> task2 "aaaabbaabrrrzz"
 [('a',4),('b',2),('a',2),('b',1),('r',3),('z',2)]
 λ> 
 λ> task2 "a"
 [('a',1)]
 λ> 
 λ> task2 ""
 []
 λ>
```