# In Haskell, create a list with sublists with repeating elements from a given list

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to change a list from this: `[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]`

to a list like this: `[[0,0,0], [1,1,1], [2,2,2]]`

I'm restrained to only using the prelude and no recursion, which makes this extra difficult.

Comment: Anything's possible. [`foldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) is the list type's catamorphism, which means by definition it can do everything recursion could as far as iterating over a list is concerned. You're going to want to make use of it for this exercise.

Comment: This is exactly [group](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.16/base-4.14.3.0/Data-List.html#v:group)

Comment: voting to close. No attempt.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a variation on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69871708/11582270).

1. `foldr` is from prelude
2. `stepFn` isn't recursive

```hs
task4 :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
task4 cs = foldr stepFn [[]] cs
  where
    stepFn c [[]]          = [[c]]  -- simple case
    stepFn c ((s:xs) : ps) =        -- please try to write the rest
```

> `if(c==s) then (c:c:xs):ps else [c]:((s:xs):ps)`

Test:

```
Prelude> task4 [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]
[[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
Prelude> task4 [0,0,1,1,1,2,2]
[[0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2]]
```